# Zurb Foundation + Compass project creation : Too many arguments were specified

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

When I create a new Zurb Foundation project using compass with :

```
compass create <project-name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

I get the following error :

> Too many arguments were specified.

I found a workaround using sudo, but then my IDE cannot edit files, so this is not a solution.

Moreover, if I remove the project name from the command the project is created but then, when I launch :

```
compass watch
```

Instead of monitoring my .sass files, it creates a watch folder containing new .sass and .css files.

Any idea to make work zurb-foundation + compass watch with this command without sudo ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your commands slightly wrong.
Assuming you have Foundation installed (via bower) and compass as well...your syntax should be:

```
foundation new <your-project>
```

Link here: [Compass Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html)

Comment: Command is this one : run compass create <project-name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation Taken from : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/compass.php

Comment: That is Foundation 3 docs? Foundation is now on Version 5. Do you absolutely have to use v3?

Comment: As of version 5, Foundation is no longer a Compass extension (at least as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using the following commands :

```
compass [an existing folder] -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
sudo compass watch
```

I had to add a sudo for the watch anyway but it's not locking my files anymore.

For those of you who might be interested in automating the process of creating a new compass + zurb foundation project and launching compass watch, I created the following function for my .bashrc / .zshrc

```
function foundation()
{
    mkdir $1;
    compass $1 -r zurb-foundation --using foundation;
    cd $1;
    sudo compass watch;
}
```

Hope this might be useful to some.